# The meaning of "I am not snapping as much"

Tags: meaning, humor

Would you please help me and tell me why did the audience laugh when they heard the speaker saying saying the following sentences? I heard them like this:

1. "over time I would say, actually I am not snapping as much, myself, that's what would I say. I think he (my partner) would even say that too. It's in 35:33 in the video
2. they also laughed here, I really couldn't understand why.

Here is the video: [Being Mindful of Emotion to Validate Self and Other - Kelly Koerner, PhD](https://youtu.be/ojWEDcHBLig?t=2162)

Comment: The laugh is partly due to the speaker's pause, letting the audience wonder if that's true or not that she snaps at her partner less.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, "snapping" could mean any of the following:

speaking sharply or angrily

breaking down emotionally

taking informal photographs.

It can also have its original meaning of breaking something, such as a stick or a rope, suddenly.

The joke is, presumably, a play on at least two of these meanings. For instance another character might say that they aren't breaking down emotionally these days and the person speaking would say that they weren't snapping as much meaning that they weren't speaking angrily on so many occasions, particularly to their partner.

I have now watched parts of the video and I see that the speaker is comparing the way in which she deals with patients and the way she interacts with her partner. The joke is that she believes that her own self treatment has reduced the extent to which she "snaps" at her partner and that this is a comparatively minor problem compared to those of her patients. Also her partner may not agree that she does not snap as much. Her revelation of part of her private life is a lightening of the serious mood of her talk.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help here. I really appreciate it. If you just can help me here for the last time here in 38:24. Did She say " here you are in lunch or " here you are not sure thinking"? 

Comment: @Princess the sound quality is quite poor and I'm British rather than American or Canadian so her accent isn't entirely clear to me but I think she says something like "here you are at lunch and thinking..." I imagine that it's getting close to lunch time and that she's hoping that the audience members don't mind doing an exercise while they are becoming distracted by thoughts of the break and lunch. Having said that I'm not too sure. Try to ignore it, it's not necessary to understanding the lecture.

Comment: Much appreciated. I am grateful to you and your big help 

Comment: No, no, no.  The speaker is no longer a member of one of the gangs in The West Side Story.